# The hebrew meaning of the name Laila

Tags: names, malach-angel, abraham

My wife and I just had a beautiful little girl and we named her Laila Grace.  I was curious of the meaning of Laila and decided to search the web.  I came to an interesting comment that I am hoping for this forum to shed some light on.

> In the Torah, G-d Almighty sent Lailah, angel of the night, to Abraham.  In part to protect and to fight for him in a night time battle against vile, corrupt and ungodly kings.  They fought side by side and easily destroyed the sinners.

As a Christian, I am also curious where this is found in the Torah or Bible.

Comment: Mazel Tov on your new baby! I know an older lady with this name pronounced the Hebrew way "Lie-la". This may be good for you so she doesn't grow up always being asked if she is named after the Clapton song.

Comment: It is not found in the Torah at all.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lailah

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In modern Hebrew "Laila" (hebrew לילה) translates directly to "night". It is very common in the old testament for names to carry meanings.

The name Laila (לילה) is special in the regard it appears in the book of Genesis:

> וַיִּקְרָא אֱלֹהִים לָאוֹר יוֹם, וְלַחֹשֶׁךְ קָרָא לָיְלָה

In English this is:

> And God called the light Day, and the darkness he called Night

Translating with the name in place, it reads 'and the darkness he called Layla'. It's worth mentioning that darkness (חשך) does not have a negative context in Hebrew it sometimes carries in English, there is another word for that "Ofel" (אפל). The Tanach uses the word Laila in 47 places.

The angel Lailah does not appear in the Tanach. It does however appear in the Zohar as an angel as well as in the Gmara (Babylonian Talmud).

Comment: The Hebrew word for night rhymes with "eye - la." The word that rhymes with "say - la", e.g. [the Eric Clapton song](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layla), doesn't mean anything in Hebrew. But it's quite close to the Aramaic word for "beyond", also found in Jewish liturgy: take the Eric Clapton song, and put a glottal stop after the L: say "leh - SAY - la" without the S.

Comment: @Shalom There is Leil in Hebrew, and adding _ah_ to form a name is pretty common.

Comment: @DoubleAA that's a real stretch. You can take a boy's name and feminize it -- Shmuela, Binyamina, Davida, and the like. But "leil" means "night of", it needs to connect to another word. (And "night" is already feminine in Hebrew.)

Comment: @Shalom Night is _not_ feminine in Hebrew. בלילה הזה not בלילה הזאת

Comment: @DoubleAA woops! Sorry. I think that was my brain's way of saying "layla tov."

Comment: @DoubleAA Doesn’t the Gra there have a piece on why it uses the feminine לילה with the masculine הזה?

Comment: @donielf I don't know where there is, but לילה is masculine in all contexts TTBOMK

Comment: @DoubleAA מה נשתנה הלילה הזה

Answer (score 3):

The Targum written in Aramaic uses the word 'leilya' as the translation of the Hebrew word 'Layla', night. But the common pronunciation is Arabic in origin.
The place in the Talmud where you will find the angel called Layla is in tractate Sanhedrin page 96a. 
And congratulations!

Answer (score 0):

Lailah is meant absolutely 'night' Not angel of night.posting of father of Laila grace is not in Torah (angel of night)  is not correct.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! You are correct that "lailah" means night. I am not sure what you meant to say "posting of father of Laila grace is not in Torah (angel of night) is not correct." perhaps consider [editing](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/62309/edit) this to clarify. Consider also taking the following two-minute [tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more. Hope to see you around.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are referring to the common Hebrew name of Leah, found in the Bible and the second wife of Jacob.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! I’m not sure this exactly answers the question, since, as evidenced by other answers, Laila is actually a name with a Hebrew origin, independent of Leah (who, just so you know, was actually Jacob’s first wife).